# Icon doesn't load

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation

Hi my icons don't load and i don't know why. They should appear in the navigation. Im very new and don't find good new resources to learn. 
Everything is old. Some links would help thank u.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the future, it is substantially better to post the actual code instead of screenshots of your code. Stack overflow provides a way to format source code in questions and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetView` needs to set the image on the `ImageButton` in the layout. Notice that you aren't even using the `items` in your adapter? Instead of using a list of `ImageButton` why not accept the drawables, and then set the image of each `ImageButton` from the items? See an updated version of `GetView` (below) which should get you a working example of setting the image on the `ImageButton` in each of your buttons.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = convertView;
     if(v == null){
         v = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MenuButtonLayout, parent, false);
     }
     var imageButton = v.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.myButton); 
     imageButton.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Noten);
     return v;
 }
```